# If $\rho$ is a correlation coefficient, what is $1-\rho$?

Tags: regression, correlation

If $\rho$ is a Pearson correlation coefficient, say between the price of crude oil and gold, what is $1-\rho$?

More specifically, what is the interpretation of  $1-\rho$? Would it be the degree of disassociation between two series?

Comment: It is meaningless. Why would you calculate it?

Comment: @Tim I am just trying to see if there is a notion of degree of disassociation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking for a degree of dissociation, as you stated in the comments, you might want to look at $1-\rho^2$. $\rho^2$ is always between $0$ and $1$ so subtracting  it from $1$ will lead to values between $0$ and $1$.

$\rho^2$ is often used in linear regression where it is known as $R^2$

Comment: As a point of English usage, "dissociation" is preferable.

Comment: @NickCox As always, your language help is very welcome and I edited the text.

Comment: Thanks guys!!!!!

Comment: I think the notion of degree of disassociation would be different from $1-R^2=1-\rho^2$, because the coefficient of determination shows the variation in the dependent variable explained by a set of the independent variables. Then, the variation unexplained by this set doesn't necessarily mean the degree of disassication. Also, I admit I was ambiguous in terms of between which objects I look for the disassociation. Outside of the regression context, I meant just two simple time series data.

Comment: @Bernhard What do you think?

Comment: @NickCox What do you think?

Comment: Obvious attempts are $-1\times \rho$ or $1-|\rho |$ or $1-R^2$. If you state, that $1-R^2$ isn't a good measure of degree of dissociation, than the obvious question becomes: How do you define "degree of dissociation". What are the boundaries, how do we recognise a good measure?

Comment: $1 - \rho$ has no interesting or useful interpretation. I don't have a different way to explain that, except that plotting it as a function of $\rho$ may make this clear.

Comment: Thanks guys. It helps!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the (Pearson) correlation coefficient is between $-1$ and $1$, so if you have a value of $0.6$ then $1-0.6=0.4$, which is... nothing. Or if the value is $-0.4$ then $1-(-0.4)=1.4$.

Comment: that sounds right. thanks. i am just trying to see if there is a notion of degree of disassociation...

Comment: do you mean dissociation as negative correlation ? If so Pearson correlation coefficient already gives you the answer (at least for linear correaltion) ? or indepandance ? Il so, the are numbers of tests .. but 0 as correlation coefficent doesn't indicate indepdance .. and you should remember that peason correlation coefficient deal with linear correlation only ..

Comment: 0.4 isn't nothing, but I think you mean it doesn't measure or correspond to 0.4 of anything of interest,not quite the same.